# xmpp stream did disconnect Calling after connect in ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, openfire, xmppframework

Hi I am working with the xmpp framework working fine till yesterday But I don't know what happen suddenly xmpp didDisConnect method calling

```
- (void)xmppStreamDidDisconnect:(XMPPStream *)sender withError:(NSError *)error
```

where I am missing.I know if username password wrong then it will be disconnected.But I checked my username it is fine and it is showing below error

```
Error Domain=GCDAsyncSocketErrorDomain Code=4 "Read operation timed out" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Read operation timed out
```

below is the connect method

```
- (BOOL)connect
 {

if (![xmppStream isDisconnected]) {
    return YES;
}
myJID =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@servername",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"FinalUserNameJID"]];


NSString *password1=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"smsVerificationNumber"];

// If you don't want to use the Settings view to set the JID,
// uncomment the section below to hard code a JID and password.
//
// myJID = @"user@gmail.com/xmppframework";
// myPassword = @"";

if (myJID == nil || password1 == nil) {
    return NO;
}


[xmppStream setMyJID:[XMPPJID jidWithString:myJID]];
password = password1;

NSError *error = nil;

if (![xmppStream connectWithTimeout:XMPPStreamTimeoutNone error:&error])
{

    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error connecting"
                                                        message:@"See console for error details."
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString( @"O_K", @"OK")
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];

    DDLogError(@"Error connecting: %@", error);

    return NO;
}


return YES;
```

}

Please help me if any body face this issue.Thankyou

Comment: showyour connect method .

Comment: please check the updated answer

Comment: @MOHAMMADISHAQ please check updated answer.and please tell why this xmppStreamDidDisconnect call.i mean which cases.

Comment: please add your complete JID and server port too , Make sure your server is on at that port

Comment: for test server use "Spark" or any other open source Jabber client .

Comment: @MOHAMMADISHAQ Thanks for the Replay Only some times it is disconnecting is there any way to connect again

Comment: yes , in there is a delegate that let you know that socket disconnect , in that you can connect again

Comment: @MOHAMMADISHAQ can you please check this issue i am facing this issue from today i don't know how to resolve it <https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/issues/739>

Comment: There is nothing at this link .

Comment: @MOHAMMADISHAQ issue #739 in xmpp frmaework.I'm getting  policy violation error. If you know any thing else please help me .Like same this issue <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37652062/policy-violation-error-in-xmpp-ios>