# Policy-Violation Error in Xmpp ios?

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework

HI I'm working with the xmpp framework.every thing working fine till yesterday.But suddenly I'm facing below error then server Disconnected

```
<stream:error xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams"><policy-violation xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-streams"/></stream:error>
```

Why this error I'm receiving.Please if any body knows help me.Thanks in advance 
and also I'm getting another error like below

```
SEND: <iq type="error" to="manager.ip-1-148" id="30-22829"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:version"/><error type="cancel" code="501"><feature-not-implemented xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error></iq>
2016-06-08 03:16:00:834[12715:9b03] RECV: <message xmlns="jabber:client" from="manager.ip--148" to="919553@ip-172-148/Smack"><body>You are using an invalid client, and therefore will be disconnected. Please ask your system administrator for client choices.</body></message>
```

Comment: https://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3920.html check this , There is some issue with entity or stanza you are sending at server.

Comment: Hi i'm facing this issue , have you faced this type of problems
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37831308/user-presence-not-receiving-xmpp-ios