# User presence not receiving xmpp ios

Tags: ios, xmpp, openfire, xmppframework

I have added user to my roster using this rest api
http://192.168.1.39:9090/plugins/restapi/v1/users/hello/roster
Header

```
Authorization:FBeGHvBFSa7JsLL3
Content-Type:application/xml
```

Body

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<rosterItem>
    <jid>vinod@192.168.1.39</jid>
    <nickname>vinod</nickname>
    <subscriptionType>3</subscriptionType>
</rosterItem>
```

user successfully added to roster but user presence not receiving in my iOS application.

please help me for this , what i missing in my code or other things

Comment: as per my knowledge after authentication success   are you sending goOnline Xml to server.

Comment: Yes i'm sending in goOnline Method
XMPPPresence *presence = [XMPPPresence presence]; 
[[self xmppStream] sendElement:presence];

Comment: Then are you check this delegate method `didReceivePresence` when other user came to online  then this method will show you. or else you can use fetchedController

Comment: Yes i have added debug on didReceivePresence method but this is not calling when other user is coming online

Comment: sometime i received this type of error in presence delegate method

 `<presence xmlns="jabber:client" to="hello@es-arifkhan/361knvwked" from="vinod@192.168.1.39" type="error"><error code="404" type="cancel"><remote-server-not-found xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error></presence>`

Comment: So may be your not authenticated check the authenticated delegates and also your server is connected or not

Comment: user successfully connected to server , showing online in openfire

Comment: Okay then try `NSFetchedController` may you get the list of user from your roaster.In that you will able to get the user is online or offline

Comment: `[[self xmppRoster] acceptPresenceSubscriptionRequestFrom:jid andAddToRoster:YES];` while adding to roaster you must use this line try this also

Comment: fetched controller getting all user that are in roster but showing all user in offline section

Comment: I tried with this code
`[[self xmppRoster] acceptPresenceSubscriptionRequestFrom:jid andAddToRoster:YES];' 
but getting  error 
`<presence xmlns="jabber:client" to="hello@es-arifkhan/361knvwked" from="vinod@192.168.1.39" type="error"><error code="404" type="cancel"><remote-server-not-found xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error></presence>'

Comment: yes you can show all user who are in offline and online users aswell

Comment: where did you use that code

Comment: I have added this code when adding user in my contact list

Comment: i would be very thankfull to you , please solve my issue

Comment: are you sure you are connected to openfire every time.Okay send me your domain name and port then i will check on my code

Comment: i'm using my local server , you can remote my pc using team viewver

Comment: no way i am in office if you want after 7pm.I am free

Comment: okey thanks i'll let you know after 7 pm , what your contact no. you can delete after 2 minutes from commnet

Comment: 9782135185 this is my contact no

Comment: which openfire version are you using ?

Comment: I think 4.0 version

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114820/discussion-between-suthar-and-bittoo).